# Read from dataset and place into objects

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object, dataset

I have a external dataset which is filled with the following data: userid, itemid, rating. I want to read this data into an userpreference object for each user. The userpreference object contains a userid, an itemid array and an ratings array. I chose an array because the performance needs to be as fast as possible. I've tried to do it without objects and used a 2D-array instead. This works, but I want it to be OOP and use objects. I'm stuck at placing the data into objects.

An example of a dataset is:
1,101,2.5
1,106,3.0
2,101,3.0
4,106,4.5
4,103,3.0
1,103,3.0
1,104,3.5
5,102,4.0

What my code looks like

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{ 
        //UserPreference bestaat uit userid, itemid[] en preferences[].     
        UserPreference [][] rating = new UserPreference[8][107];

        int[][] userPref = new int[8][107]; //2d array test

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("userinfo.data"));
        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] userratings = line.split(",");
            int userColumn = Integer.parseInt(userratings[0]);
            int itemColumn = Integer.parseInt(userratings[1]);
            double ratingColumn = Double.parseDouble(userratings[2]);            

            System.out.println(userColumn + " " + itemColumn + " " + ratingColumn);

            rating[userColumn][itemColumn] = ratingColumn;  

            userPref[userColumn][itemColumn] = (int) ratingColumn; //2d array test

        }           
        br.close();

        System.out.println("Rating: " + userPref[1][101]); // this works as an example, but not OO and reads out as an int instead of a double
        System.out.println("Rating: " + rating[1][101]); //this does not work, because ratingcolumn is no object.
    } }
```

The ratingcolumn is not recognized as an object. I tried to do it like the 2d array I've used before, but it does not work the same. I hope someone can help me in the right direction.

Greetings,

Alfred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OO solution could be:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        HashMap<Integer, User> users = new HashMap<Integer, User>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("userinfo.data"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] userratings = line.split(",");
            int userColumn = Integer.parseInt(userratings[0]);
            int itemColumn = Integer.parseInt(userratings[1]);
            double ratingColumn = Double.parseDouble(userratings[2]);
            User user = users.get(userColumn);
            if (user == null) {
                user = new User(userColumn);
                users.put(userColumn, user);
            }
            user.add(new Item(itemColumn, ratingColumn));
        }
        br.close();

        for (User user : users.values()) {
            for (Item item : user.getItems()) {
                System.out.println(user.getId() + "\t" + item.getId() + "\t" + item.getRating());
            }
        }
    }
```

With this two classes:

```
public class User {
    int id;
    ArrayList<Item> items;

    public User(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void add(final Item item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}



public class Item {
    int id;
    double rating;

    public Item(final int id, final double rating) {
        this.id = id;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(final double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo! It made me look from a different angle and translate it into a OOP way.